# error while removing the stop-words from the text

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, stop-words, data-preprocessing

I am trying to remove stopwords from my data and I have used this statement to download the stopwords.

stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

This has character 'd' as one of the stopwords. So, when I apply this to my function it is removing 'd' from the word. Please see the attached picture for the reference and guide me how to fix this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0JjI.png)

Comment: Please update the question with a reproducible coding example

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the code and noticed that you are applying the `rem_stopwords` function on the clean_text column, while you should apply it on tweet column.

Otherwise, NLTK removes d, I, and other characters when they are independent tokens, a token here is a word after you split on spaces, so if you have i'd, it will not remove d nor I since they are combined into a word. However if you have 'I like Football' it will remove I, since it will be an independent token.

You can try this code, it will solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

nltk.download('stopwords')
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

df['clean_text'] = df['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word.lower() not in (stop)]))
```

Comment: I changed the code as you said. But now, I am getting blank column of  clean_text.

Comment: Can you try this line of code instead of the `rem_stopwords` function? 
`df['clean_text'] = df['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word.lower() not in (stop)]))`